# Elliptical billiards and eccentricity

Tags: conic-sections, billiards

I have to do an exploration in maths. I was thinking to do it on how the angle of incidence and reflection vary with the eccentricity of the ellipse. Do you think could be interesting? Do you have any suggestions for the method? I was thinking to extend it on ellipsoid billiards.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't understand what "the angle of incidence and reflection vary with the eccentricity of the ellipse" means. And what is "an exploration in maths"? If you want to learn something about maths and billiards, read this: https://www.personal.psu.edu/sot2/books/billiardsgeometry.pdf